# In PointCloud2 what is Position Transformer property

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Rviz/PointCloud2 what is the Position Transformer  property. It shows one item XYZ but does not allow it to be modified. I can not find a definition of this property in the documentation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/102666/in-pointcloud2-what-is-position-transformer--property/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Position Transformer property allows you to set the position of the points in the XYZ coordinate system in order to be viewed in 3D sensibly. Its similar to Color Transformer, which allows you to set different ways of color patterns to the points for sensible perception.

---

Originally posted by [sudhanshu_mittal](https://answers.ros.org/users/5307/sudhanshu_mittal/) with karma: 311 on 2013-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2013-11-19**:
It does not seem to allow me to override it. Can I use this to translate to optical frame to base-link. That is to say it would allow me to apply a set of rotations to the cloud points or remap the XYZ to ZYX optical.